# Crosswalk not supported on Mobile First Platform

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am building mobile app.
I would like to use Crosswalk with Mobile First Platform (MFP).
Currently MFP does not support Crosswalk

(See: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/hello-world/integrating-mfpf-sdk-in-cordova-applications/)

What is a rough estimated date of MFP supporting Crosswalk?
Mostly, I will use MFP. To use with MFP, instead of using Crosswalk, what other feature/library/Swappable WebView do you recommend me to use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Development estimations or confirmations cannot be provided. If you are an IBM customer you can contact IBM directly and submit your inquiries and business justifications.

When using MobileFirst Platform it is currently not possible to swap the provided Cordova library with any available alternative at this time.